# Which SE site is suitable for asking about optimization of a mobile application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, software-engineering-se

I want to post this problem in the suitable SE site. But, I don't know which is suitable.

My problem is:

> In my office there is one iOS app which having 60 mb app size in
>   store. Now, am going to handle that project. Am believe that I can
>   reduce the size of the app by some optimizing. My question is, *What
>   are the steps commonly followed by professional to optimize the
>   application by reduce the size?*.

I only want help as for which Stack Exchange site I should post on.

Comment: I would suggest Programmers for that general question, and SO for any specific questions about the code. I am not entirely sure though.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson this "general" question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Wasn't entirely sure, I don't use Porgramming.SE.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson when in doubt, [it is safer to abstain of recommending the site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268722/839601)

Comment: Just a minor typo: The title should be "Which *SE* site", not SO (Stack Overflow is 1 of many sites in SE)

Comment: @AngusAtkinson [case in point](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/290135/basic-principles-to-follow-for-reducing-the-size-of-an-ios-application "that 'general question' has been posted at Programmers, voted down and closed"). "Recommending an asker to a site when one is not well familiar with it tends to do more harm than good. Inexperienced users often simply repost their questions as-is and get frustrated when it turns out off-topic, closed, and voted down..."

Answer (score 4):

To be honest I think that question is way too broad for any of the sites your question could possible fit.

To be successful you'll need to have analyzed your exact problem a little bit better because that would enable you to ask for example this question on [programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> My app is 60MB which is partly caused by the same image being included several times in the application bundle. This is cause by the Resourcemanager class that is in each subnamespace because *resaons*. This [code example] shows how we use that now. How should I restructure/refactor that code to have only one image included?

For [CodeReview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> My app is 60MB which is caused by some large code modules that contain largely duplicate code but due to *reasons* we can't seem to split this in common code and specific code. How can we do that if my [working code example]  looks like this.

For [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> My app is 60MB which is caused by a large resource file. I want that resource file to be smaller by using a compression algorithm. I used arj to compress the file by hand but when I call `[NSInflate resource::]` my app fails with *no decompressor found*. How should I use NSInflate to get the original file?

Remember for all sites you intend to post on to first visit that site to get an idea what kind of questions are asked, to study their help center, specially the [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is on-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When in doubt ask on the specific site-meta first to verify if your question is welcome there and/or seek help in one of the site-specific chat rooms.

Comment: Thats why am using word "followed by professional". I think Programmers.se is suitable. Because help center says the design of programs. So optimization of application is also under design. What you feel about this.

Comment: Really not in its current state @UdanPirappu you need to give more context for that question fly there. Just visit a site chatroom or re-check on their meta.

Comment: K. Bt even asking bssic procedure is not giving clear.